# Installed VS Code, not sure how to run it or where to find it

Tags: debian, snap

I'm new to Debian (Mate) and I am pretty sure I installed Visual Studio Code through snap. However I can't find it anywhere and don't know what I should type in the terminal to open vscode. I have tried just typing "code" wich was suggested somewhere. And I have also tried searching for visual or code or visual studio code and I can't find anything on it. It also isn't in usr share applications.

So I'm either looking for a shortcut or anything clickable that says VS Code or how to run it from the command line cause I don't know what name it should have and I can't find anything on "how" to run it either. I know how to get to root by now because sudo doesn't work. But I don't know how to run anything. Is it just typing the name (that I don't know). I would prefer a clickable option but if you can give the full command I should type I would be happy as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be just `code` or `code .`

Comment: So I type code in console without anything else? It works for for example nano. But code or code . isn't recognized. It did install something cause I saw it do the work through the terminal. But if it isn't working I would like to uninstall that part before trying to install VS Code again.

Answer (score 0):

I know the issue is old, but I had the same one.
Maybe, for those facing this too here is what I found to do while googling:

In the terminal type this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, typing `code` will open VS.